# How can I install cronolog in Tomcat for daily log rotate?

Tags: tomcat, logrotate

When i wanted to lotate log daily, I was editing catalina.sh in other to redirect log to cronolog.

I think it is bad solution because catalina.sh file is executable shell file.

Can I config it using editing properties or any files in conf directory ?

Is there another good solution?

new:

```
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start 2>&1 \
      | cronolog "$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.
%Y-%m-%d.out >> /dev/null &
```

old:

```
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
      >> "$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a proper logging framework instead of System.out? You have at least three at your disposal:

- [java.util.logging](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) and use the [RollingFileHandler](http://www.x4juli.org/api/org/x4juli/handlers/RollingFileHandler.html) from http://www.x4juli.org/
- [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html) and use [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html)
- [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) and use [RollingFileAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html)

Using any of these you will be able to control what you log (using levels - debug, info, warn, error), where you log (turn loggers on and off) and log into different targets - files, db, mail, jms etc.

Comment: Thank you. I used the log4j and console appender. Your point give me  good understanding.

Answer (score 0):

David Rabinowitz makes a good point, but to answer your question, your use of cronolog is fine.